# Can clients with slow connection break down blocking-socket-based server?

Tags: multithreading, sockets, blocking

By definition of blocking sockets, all calls to send() or recv() are blocking until the whole networking operation is finished. This can take some time especially when using tcp and talking to client with slow connection. This is of course solved by introducing threads and thread pools. But what happens if all threads are blocked by some slow client? For example your server wants to serve 10 000+ clients with 100 threads sending data to all users every second. That means each thread would have to call send() 100 times every second. What happens if at some point 100 clients are connected with connections so slow that one call to send()/recv() takes 5 seconds to complete for them(or possibly attacker who does it on purpose). In that case all 100 threads are blocking and everyone else waits. How is this generally solved? Adding more threads to threadpool is probably not a solution since there can always be more slow clients and going for some really high number of threads would introduce even more problems with context switching resource consumption etc.

Comment: That's why you would use non-blocking I/O for serving 10000+ clients.

Comment: doeas that mean that blocking I/O based servers are basicaly unscalable in terms of number of clients?

Comment: @plomba Yes. It would be quite foolish to use blocking I/O in an application intended to scale to more than a few hundred connections at most.

Comment: It's kind of foolish to use blocking I/O at all IMHO, since even in a small-scale server with just a few clients, it's difficult to e.g. have the server exit cleanly (e.g. in response to a SIGHUP or etc) if any of the threads are blocked inside lengthy blocking I/O calls.  (if your main thread calls e.g. `pthread_join()` to wait for them to complete, your server might not shut down for a very long time, if ever; OTOH if it doesn't call that, you'll have a race condition that will cause your server to occasionally crash on exit)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can clients with slow connection break down blocking-socket-based server?

Yes, they can.  And it does consume resources on the server side.  And if too much of this happens, you can end up with a form of "denial of service".

Note that this is worst if you use blocking I/O on the server side because you are tying down a thread while the response is being sent.  But it is still a problem with non-blocking I/O.  In the latter case, you consume server side sockets, port numbers, and memory to buffer the responses waiting to be sent.

If you want to guard your server against the effects of slow clients, it needs to implement a timeout on sending responses.  If the server finds that it is taking too long to write a response ... for whatever reason ... it should simply close the socket.

Typical web servers do this by default.

Finally, as David notes, using non-blocking I/O will make your server more scalable.  You can handle more simultaneous requests with less resources.  But there are still limits to how much a single server can scale.  Beyond a certain point you need a way to spread the request load over multiple servers.